# Promise inside Observable does not return value

Tags: promise, rxjs, observable, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed Microsoft PowerBi in my angular 6 project. the next codes is expecting return an powerbi report object, but nothing is returning, no idea why:

```
 private embedPowerBiReportAndGetPages(htmlElement: HTMLElement, newMyPowerbiReport: MyPowerbiReport): Observable<MyPowerbiReport> {
const config: IEmbedConfiguration = PowerbiHelper.createReportConfig(newMyPowerbiReport);
const microsoftReport: msReport = this.msPowerBiService
  .embed(htmlElement, config) as msReport;
return fromEvent(microsoftReport, 'loaded')
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.logger.debug('PowerBI: loaded')),
    mergeMap(async() => {
      this.logger.debug('PowerBI: embed pages loaded');
      const msPages: Page[] = await microsoftReport.getPages();
      this.logger.debug('PowerBI: msPages', msPages);
      newMyPowerbiReport.pages = msPages.map((page: Page) => PowerbiHelper.msPageToEmbeddedPageMapper(page, newMyPowerbiReport));
      this.logger.debug('PowerBI: newMyPowerbiReport pages updated', newMyPowerbiReport);
      return newMyPowerbiReport;
    }),
    finalize(() => microsoftReport.off('loaded'))
  );
```

}

Well the promise inside mergeMap is called and also returns result, from the logger I can see PowerBI: newMyPowerbiReport pages updated and the pages array. but it nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally fixed, there is nothing with this code, the problem was in the parent method, I've used forkjoin in the parent method, it seems that forkjoin does not subscribe this observable, change forkjoin with [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) and everything work as the sun shines .